# MySQL to count rows in between two numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query to count rows in between two numbers. I have a table called **purchase_order** and in that there is a column called **age**, And in that age column simple numeric data is populating like 30, 55, 90, 95, 100....So for example I want only count rows in between 90 to 100. So far I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM office_in_box.purchase_order WHERE age  BETWEEN 90 and 110
```

Also I want the count of all rows in between 90 to 110.

Thanks

Comment: `select count(*) from ...`

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`COUNT`](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqnci795DOAhWBmpQKHVXvD4sQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Fmysql%2Fen%2Fcounting-rows.html&usg=AFQjCNEWYmZU1eMqiypBPZkp5lVOms29KQ&sig2=1RuyTQy117hBftLLi2u4eg):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM office_in_box.purchase_order WHERE age  BETWEEN 90 and 110
```

Answer (score 2):

> The **[COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)** function returns the number of rows that matches a specified criteria.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM office_in_box.purchase_order 
WHERE age BETWEEN 90 and 110
```